# IPA file extraction

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to extract IPA file from project to run it on a real device to check the functionalities .
I'm extracting it through the product folder and compressing it but it is showing error in iPhone that this file can't run.

Comment: what kind of error?

Comment: made project file to iTunes using iPad file but when we connect the iPhone with mac and want to run the app in iPhone it popups error that file can't open. Is there any alternative way?

Comment: Extract Ipa?what you mean?Do you want to built a archive or you want to run the ipa on iphone?please be clear and concise

Comment: I have clicked the product folder and .app file and reveal it in Finder where i compress it and change extension to ipa then it become iTunes file than i plug an iPhone with my mac and try to run it but the result is error. @VladHatko

Comment: i have a project and now i want to test it on real device how can i do this? @Arun

Answer (score 1):

To test an app on real device ,you must have development and adhoc provisioning profile for the app.

To know how to create certificates and provisioning profile, you can check this link: [App id, certificates and provisioning profile](https://www.raywenderlich.com/127936/submit-an-app-part-1)

Then set the provisioning profile to your app target. If everything is right so far, then create an archive by Choosing Product -> Archive in Xcode and follow the steps. When Organizer window open in this process, tap on Export, appears on the right side of the window to extract the IPA file.

Comment: how to get adhoc provisioning profile? @Jitendra Solanki

Answer (score 1):

```
To test your app on real device you need a developer account,once you got a developer account just go to general on project target and enable automatic signing,it will create automatic provisional profile and certificate for you.i will let you know the steps below.

 1)Get developer account with 99 dollars per annum.

 2)Import your developer account by selecting Xcode->Preferences->Accounts and add your account by entering account name and password.

 3)Now goto general and enable automatic signing,it will register your device and create provisional profile with certificate automatically.

4)Clean build and run your project with your device by connecting to Xcode.

Enjoy.....
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse work .

1 . You need to change .ipa extension to .zip

2 . Now you can watch .app file now drag this file to your device from **Windows > Device**

**Another way for creating of ipa**

If you want to work this ipa file then you need to create ipa as  below:

> 1. Add necessary profiles and adjust build settings.
> 2. Set device as target to run the application.
> 3. Build the product.
> 4. Go to Products->yourAppName.app. Right click and show in finder.
> 5. Drag & drop to itunes profile and binary file.
> 6. Select app in iTunes and right click to show in Finder. And there you can get the .ipa file.